# Linking static libs to dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, clr

What is the best way to join few static libs into one dll with exported symbols.
Dll will be used as a contact point between unmanaged C++ code (backend) to managed C# code (frontend) using CLI.

I would like to mention that there is no possibility to change code in static libs so additional wrapper like dll is needed because of compile options compatibility with CLR wrapper.

I've read following link
[Linking to static lib with managed components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023137/linking-to-static-lib-with-managed-components?rq=1) 
and it says:

> FYI: This is no longer valid as of (at least) Visual Studio 2013. I am compiling with /clr to .lib, and link it in a DLL (also compiled with /clr).

but I use Visual 2013 and it still get error about CLR and /MT incompatibility.

Comment: To close this question i will write what I have done. Maybe some will have another idea or consider this solution as useful tip. As I said I have few static libs compiled with /MT flag that cannot be changed and I would like to connect them with WPF application. I created a bridge between this two end points: one dll that connects all static libs and expose API to second CLR library...

Comment: ...CLR library has API that convert c++ function to C#. It allows to way communication by passing callback functions on C# application side. If some has better idea or some remarks about this solution i will be grateful for sharing it with me.